# Azure AppGateway path route to multiple app service webapps?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-application-gateway

**I have a WAF App Gateway**

- appgateway.eastus.cloudapp.azure.com.

**And 2 App Service web apps**

1. api-service.azurewebsites.net
2. web-ui.azurewebsites.net

Both these app services are completely different app and one of them is a JS Application and other is Java Application. Both these belong to single App Service Plan.

I'm trying to route App Gateway based on path to these app services
Eg:

- /api/* -> route to backend pool of api app service
- /* -> route to backend pool of web app service

Is it possible with App Gateway to send in the traffic based on path to the app services?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is possible. You need to place each web app in seperate backend pool. Then create path based rule to achieve your ask.

If you face any difficulty during the implementation, let me know.

Comment: Here is what I'm doing.

#1. Created 2 Backend Pools for both the webapps.
#2. Created Basic listener with port 8080 (not sure if I need to create Multi-Site Listener)
#3. Left HTTP Settings and Frontend IP Configurations as defaults.
#4. Rules - Create path-based routing, with above created Listener, Default backend pool to Azure created backendPool, Default Http settings and then created 2 routes -> /* and /api/* and assigned respective backend pools. Still getting 502 :/

Comment: The reason why you are getting 502 might be because if the probe failure. Create a custom probe and add it to the HTTP settings and check if the backend is healthy.

Comment: Unable to retrieve health status data. Check presence of NSG/UDR blocking access to ports 65503-65534 from Internet to Application Gateway. I've opened all my inbound and outbound ports with wildcard :/

Comment: Do you have a VPN or express route connect to this vnet having default route advertised?

Comment: No... its just app gateway in vnet (subnet) and trying to access app service web apps which stays in App Service Plan by itself.

Comment: If you have NSG, try disassociate it for testing purpose and we can add it back later

Comment: After few tries, I was able to get this to working. (but not completely satisfied)

Here is what I did... Deleted my entire app server config.
#1. Created App Server, Listener with 8080 port, rules with default backend pool to one of my app servers, and then path /api/* to different backend pool. 

One with default backend pool is working with publicIP:8080/ -> goes to app server 1, and publicIP:8080/api/ routes to same app server 2.

Comment: @SiddharthaThota , can you let me know, why you are not completely satisfied? Is the current setup working as expected? Let me know the exact limitation, I can try to help you.

Comment: Hello, I was configuring the listeners wrong, I've configured it correctly now and our Application is up and running just the way I want :)